# Bug in JTable - same value appear after drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have a program that uses two JTables, with two buttons to transfer information between them, E.G:

```
     _____                    _____
    |     |                  |     |           
    |  A  |  Button 1 (>>>)  |  B  | 
    |     |  Button 2 (<<<)  |     |   
    |_____|                  |_____|
```

The aim of this is to transfer information between the records that update a database table, which all works fine. Then I tried to incorporate the drag and drop function. The drag and drop function only applies to Table B. It works perfectly on initialization when Table B does not have any records to populate immediately and you update it using Table A. When you transfer any in to them from Table A, you can drag and drop rows easily and the first column is sorted numerically. I have incorporated methods to automatically update the fields in the first column to increment in tens. i.e 10, 20, 30, 40 etc.

The bug comes into play when the table is initialized with existing information. When you try to drag and drop a row, two rows become identical using the same number of indices. E.G

```
Index   | First Column Value  | ID  | ( remaining columns omitted)
  0              10             1 
  1              20             2
  2              30             3
  3              40             4
```

Lets say I move index 3 to index 1, the table would become:

```
Index   | First Column Value  | ID  | ( remaining columns omitted)
  0              10             1
  1              20             4 
  2              20             4
  3              30             3
```

The thing is, this doesn't update this way in the database, it is updated still using the ID of 2 with the column value, even though this will not show in the table.

Code for DnD functionality:

```
 TableRowTransferHandler:

    private int[] rows    = null;
private int addIndex  = -1; //Location where items were added
private int addCount  = 0;  //Number of items added.
private int max = 0;
private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor;
private Object[] transferedObjects = null;
private JComponent source = null;
private JTable table;
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

public TableRowTransferHandler(TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter) {
    this.sorter = sorter;
    localObjectFlavor = new ActivationDataFlavor(
            Object[].class, DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, "Array of items");
}

@Override 
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {

    source = c;
    table = (JTable) c;
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

    ArrayList< Object > list = new ArrayList< Object >();

    for(int i: rows = table.getSelectedRows())
        list.add(model.getDataVector().elementAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(i)));
        transferedObjects = list.toArray();

    return new DataHandler(transferedObjects,localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
}

@Override
public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
    table = (JTable)info.getComponent();
    boolean b = info.isDrop()&&info.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor);
    table.setCursor(b?DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop:DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop);
    return b;
}

@Override 
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    return TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
}

@Override 
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
    table = (JTable)info.getComponent();
    JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    int index = dl.getRow();
    max = model.getRowCount();
    if(index<0 || index>max) index = max;
    addIndex = index;

    int previousRow;
    int id;
    for(int i =0; i < rows.length; i++){

        // Add check to make sure can not go less than 0
        previousRow = rows[i];
        int nextValue = (Integer) model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(index+1), 0);
        int actualValue = nextValue;

        if((actualValue - 10) <= 0){ 
            actualValue = 0;
        }else{

            actualValue = nextValue - 10;
        }


        id = (Integer) model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(previousRow), 1);
        table.clearSelection();
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(previousRow, previousRow);
        model.setValueAt(actualValue, table.convertRowIndexToModel(previousRow), 0);

    }

    table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    try {
        Object[] values = (Object[])info.getTransferable().getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);
        if(source==table) addCount = values.length;
        for(int i=0;i < values.length;i++) {
            int idx = index++;
            model.insertRow(idx, (Vector)values[i]);
            table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(idx, idx);
        }

        return true;
    }catch(Exception ufe) { ufe.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
}

@Override 
protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable t, int act) {
    cleanup(c, act == MOVE);
}

private void cleanup(JComponent src, boolean remove) {

    if(remove && rows != null) {
        table = (JTable)src;
        src.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        if(addCount > 0) {
            for(int i=0;i < rows.length;i++) {
                if(rows[i] >= addIndex) { rows[i] += addCount; }
            }
        }
        logger.debug("Rows length is : " + rows.length);

        for(int i=rows.length-1;i >= 0;i--)
        model.removeRow(rows[i]);

        int maxIteration = max - 1;
        for (int i1 = maxIteration; i1 >= 0; i1--){

            int value = max * 10;
            max--;
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.convertRowIndexToModel(i1),  table.convertRowIndexToModel(i1));
            model.setValueAt(value, table.convertRowIndexToModel(i1), 0);

        }
    }

    rows     = null;
    addCount = 0;
    addIndex = -1;
  }
 }
```

I have a feeling that this may be a *rendering* issue but does any one have any ideas ?

If Any one would like further examples of code if you have an idea where the bug is don't hesitate to ask, although through debugging many times I have found that it seems to be stemming from this particular class.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome.

Comment: while bugs are always a possibility with non-zero probability, claiming one requires some code that makes it reproducible (aka: SSCCE, as @AndrewThompson already suggested)

Comment: a quick check against a rendering issue is to move the mouse over the rows/cells: if so, the content will update to the expected values

Comment: Great comment and something I will note for the future. Unfortunately, this means its not a rendering issue. I will be looking into a SSCCE post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I never re visited this question but just in case anyone was having a similar issue;

I managed to sort the problem by using an array list and then re constructing the table. Remove the row based upon the selected item, then update the array based on the drop location. Completed a while back but forgot to update and just remembered now.

Hope this helps, cheers.